# Weird reputation history

Tags: discussion, reputation

Today, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2662946/ronald-araujo?tab=reputation&sort=post) profile and I wondered how he could get -30 for user removed on Aug 12. Also, in the 9 days of his membership 5 users left on him.

Is there a glitch in the system or is he just having bad luck?

Comment: One user upvoted 3 of his answers?

Comment: @StephenTG In the particular case of those votes, the person in question didn't have three posts when they were placed/removed.

Comment: Yes and he got -30 on the same minute where his reputation got above 30. Still can't understand it, there must be a bug either in the timestamps or something else...

Comment: No; not a bug. What you see is what happened, exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does look like five separate users were removed, indeed. That said, I can't comment further on that. I can say I see no evidence of a glitch, and as for luck - I wouldn't know.

There does seem to have been some odd voting going on there, though.